# How to exctract a string from terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux

When I execute a script, I obtain the following text into terminal:

```
GN status:
MAC addr: 10:98:C3:73:64:CD
Lastest Update Time: 2021-11-18 10:26:18(GMT+0)
--- Media Layer---
  TX Packet:
    Total: 68360
    Success: 68360
    Failure: 0
  RX Packet:
    Total: 751063
    Success: 751063
    Dropped: 0
    CRC Error: 313
```

All I want to do is to obtain the value 751063:

```
 RX Packet:
        Total: 751063
```

How can I show only this number into the terminal and erase all the other words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything on your own?

this will work:

```
your_command|grep 'RX Packet:' -A1|grep Total|head -1|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is right.. anyway I obtain two numbers under RX packet (total and success). How can I modify this command to obtain only one number?

Comment: From your output, this command outputs only: `751063`, not 2 numbers, which is what you were asking, OR the output from your command is not the complete output? Which script or command are you executing exactly, so that you get these stats? Please add that to the Question